# How can I shorten this super long IF and COUNTIF formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a super long formula in which I am trying to say if A2 is a number then add up how many times this number appears across four different worksheets. The number A2 changes depending on what I type in and I do have a list of these specific numbers on another worksheet but for some reason won't let me do it as a range?

So realistically I want it to be like 'Ïf A2 is a number out of this data set, add up how many times this specific number appears across the four pages.'

The below formula seems to work but is way to long and super repetitive - Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
=IFS(A2=12,COUNTIF('WEEK 1'!A2:A300,"12")+COUNTIF('WEEK 2'!A2:A300,"12")+COUNTIF('WEEK 3'!A2:A300,"12")+COUNTIF('WEEK 4'!A2:A300,"12"),A2=100823,COUNTIF('WEEK 1'!A2:A300,"100823")+COUNTIF('WEEK 2'!A2:A300,"100823")+COUNTIF('WEEK 3'!A2:A300,"100823")+COUNTIF('WEEK 4'!A2:A300,"100823"),A2=103510,COUNTIF('WEEK 1'!A2:A300,"103510")+COUNTIF('WEEK 2'!A2:A300,"103510")+COUNTIF('WEEK 3'!A2:A300,"103510")+COUNTIF('WEEK 4'!A2:A300,"103510"),A2=103509,COUNTIF('WEEK 1'!A2:A300,"103509")+COUNTIF('WEEK 2'!A2:A300,"103509")+COUNTIF('WEEK 3'!A2:A300,"103509")+COUNTIF('WEEK 4'!A2:A300,"103509"),A2=257,COUNTIF('WEEK 1'!A2:A300,"257")+COUNTIF('WEEK 2'!A2:A300,"257")+COUNTIF('WEEK 3'!A2:A300,"257")+COUNTIF('WEEK 4'!A2:A300,"257"),
```

Answer (score 0):

*This needs combination of COUNTIF & INDIRECT, rapped with SUMPRODUCT, finds value across sheets.*

**How it works:**

- In a sheet enter the sheet name like shown below.

[image]

- Now either you may name the cells or use cell references in the
  formula as I did.
- Create Drop Down in any cell, and enter list of values you have `12` ,
  `100823` & others.
- Now use this formula:

  `=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&$A$2:$A$5&"'!"&"$A$2:$A$300"),$C$1)))`
- Where Cell reference `A2:A5` has **S**heet Name.
- Cells `A2:A300` has valued to be **c**ounted.
- And cell `C1` has **D**rop Down, contains search value like `12` and others.
- *As soon you start selecting values from Drop down, get results.*
- If you named the cells `A2:A5` then replace `&$A$2:$A$5&` with Named
  Range in formula.

---

**N.B.**

- **If you don't like working with Drop Down then enter search values in
  Range and write the formula in first adjacent cell & fill down.**

[image]

- Formula in cell E2:

`=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&$A$2:$A$5&"'!"&"$A$2:$A$300"),$D2)))`

- You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work, just in a calculation intensive way (which doesn't matter in the least covering 300 cells on each of four pages) but also in a hard to create and maintain sort of way too.

There's a different, simpler way to do this. It will be easier to create and maintain.

You have two things to do after you enter a value in A2:

1. Check whether it is in the range containing the list of acceptable numbers.
2. Perform the count.

The second task is very nicely performed by your `COUNTIF()`. It is the first task that you might wish to do differently.

Presently you are testing that the value appears in the list by building an `IFS()` that has tests for each and every one of the values in the list. But if you simply test the value being in the list directly, you can use a simple `IF()` for the whole thing.

For purposes of the formula below, I envision your list being in B1:B30. Change that as apppropriate.

```
=IF( ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,B1:B30,1,FALSE)), "Entry not in list", COUNTIF('WEEK 1'!A2:A300,A2)+COUNTIF('WEEK 2'!A2:A300,A2)+COUNTIF('WEEK 3'!A2:A300,A2)+COUNTIF('WEEK 4'!A2:A300,A2))
```

The formula first checks the value in A2 is in the list. It does so in a way that if it is NOT in the list, Excel will give an error so that test is wrapped by the `ISERROR()` function. If an error exists (the value is not in the list), the formula stops and reports "Entry not in list" to you.

The test is a `VLOOKUP()` checking for the EXACT value in the list. If it IS there, then it goes to the counting step.

This way you do not need a long `IFS()` covering every value in the list. And you do not need to add a new chunk to your formula every time you add a value to that list.

Also, no need for `INDIRECT()` which many revile since it is "volatile" meaning it recalculates every time anything in the spreadsheet changes. They revile it because it could slow things down. Nowadays, that's not the least concern for almost anyone. Work with a million cells, maybe. With a thousand? You'll never notice it, ever.

But it IS more complicated and therefore harder to do than your perfect calculation of the counting. Why work harder when you can work easier? The "more complicated" thing is why I avoid it when not needed.